# Etherpad like project implemented in python

Tags: python, collaboration, etherpad

I have a web project which is implemented in python. We would like to have Etherpad like collaborative editing of texts in this project. Reusing "Etherpad lite" looks not like an option, because the exchange / synchronisation between the underlying databases would be to complicated. So the current idea was to reuse the client side of etherpad lite and to reimplement the server side. That seems to be more complicated than expected, because the client side of etherpad lite is using some node.js related code.

So before digging deeper into the etherpad lite code, I thought I would ask: Does somebody know a python project which implements etherpad lite like functionality?

Comment: I have actually been looking for something like this for quite some time. The best bet seems to be using the client side of etherpad-lite. The problem is that the communication is not decoupled as nicely as it could be. I guess your best bet would be to participate in the refactoring efforts of etherpad-lite to make it backend-agnostic.

Comment: Does it have to be Etherpad? There's also `gobby`.

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to find another project. Etherpad is the solution. It's well known, well documented and easy to integrate.

You can integrate etherpad-lite by following some rules:

- add etherpad-lite to the same domain as your python app
- use etherpad-lite http API which has everything you need
- read the doc http://etherpad.org/doc/v1.2.7/

We are currently dive into this for the CMS Plone (which is in Python).
You can find the code at https://github.com/toutpt/collective.etherpad (under development)